# Share the same node_modules folder among multiple React Apps

Tags: node.js, reactjs, node-modules

I tried to share the same "node_modules" folder among few React Apps by placing that folder in a parent directory of all React Apps, which possible according to React Docs. But "npm start" says: ERR! ELIFECYCLE.
Please Help...

I created 4 react apps using `npx create-react-app app_name` command.
And deleted all the node_modules folders from each app except one and placed it like this :

```
my_projects
    node_modules
    app_1
        src
        package.json
    app_2
        src
        package.json
    app_3
        src
        package.json
    app_4
        src
        package.json
```

React docs about this : https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders

Comment: How are you trying to accomplish this? How do the React docs say to handle it? Really going to need some more info to assist you.

Comment: @MattOestreich here I added my folder structure and docs url

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ***Symbolic or soft link***. By using the Symbolic link we can have the single ***`node_module`*** for all the projects which are all using the same version of an npm package version

After adding all the

```
cd app_1 (for all app_2,app_3,app_4)

sudo ln -s /my_projects/node_modules node_modules

npm start or yarn start
```

After that ***`node_module`*** symbolic link will be created on all the directories as follows

```
/my_projects
  node_modules
  package.json
  app_1
    node_modules   (for all its just a symbolic soft link to  /my_projects/node_modules)
    src
    package.json   (clone of /my_projects/package.json for all bellow)
  app_2
    node_modules
    src
    package.json
  app_3
    node_modules
    src
    package.json
  app_4
    node_modules
    src
    package.json
```

Using this you can maintain a single ***`node_module`*** for all the sub-projects. Also check the package manager https://pnpm.io/ for advanced use cases

Edit 1: You can remove those links by

```
rm node_modules
```

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same issue today, and I am grateful that @Vimal Raj gave me the idea.
For those who are wondering here is the same solution but in Windows:

I wanted to arrange my React apps under folder `design-patterns` so that the folder `node_modules` is used only once

```
<DIR>          node_modules (the main node_modules directory)
<DIR>          controlled-components
<DIR>          custom-hooks
<DIR>          recursive-components
<DIR>          split-screen-components
```

When you create a project, go into the project's root directory (for example: custom-hooks) and instead of saying `npm install` create a **soft link** to an already existing `node_modules` directory.
On Windows you can create **soft links** in CMD **from the subproject's folder** using the following command:

```
mklink \J node_modules ..\node_modules
```

The result should be:

```
<JUNCTION>    node_modules (shortcut to the node_modules in the parent directory)
              package-lock.json
              package.json
<DIR>         public
              server.js
<DIR>         src
```

I tried to achieve the same thing with GUI-approach (`Create shortcut` button in the context menu), but that approach has failed.